# Consulta com vários Ids e data com JPA e Spring via RESTApi

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Bom dia, estou tentando montar um consulta com Spring JPA e Rest onde posso inserir diversos IDs e datainicial e datafinal. A consulta funciona se eu colocar somente um ID com as datas. O código está dessa forma:

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public List<TagsDay> pesquisar(@RequestParam(value = "ids") List<Long> ids, TagsDayFilter tagsDayFilter){
    return tagsDayRepository.filtrar(ids, tagsDayFilter);
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface TagsDayRepositoryQuery {

    public List<TagsDay> filtrar(List<Long> ids, TagsDayFilter tagsDayFilter);

}
```

e a classe de implementação:

```
public class TagsDayRepositoryImpl implements TagsDayRepositoryQuery{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Override
    public List<TagsDay> filtrar(List<Long> ids, TagsDayFilter tagsDayFilter) {

        CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<TagsDay> criteria = builder.createQuery(TagsDay.class);

        Root<TagsDay> root = criteria.from(TagsDay.class);

        //criar as restrições
        Predicate[] predicates = criarRestricoes(ids, tagsDayFilter, builder, root);
        criteria.where(predicates);

        TypedQuery<TagsDay> query = manager.createQuery(criteria);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    private Predicate[] criarRestricoes(List<Long> ids, TagsDayFilter tagsDayFilter, CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<TagsDay> root) {

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();     

        if(ids.size() > 0) {

            for(int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
                predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("id"), ids.get(i)));  //adiciona vários ids para consulta         
            }


        }
        if(tagsDayFilter.getDataInicial() != null) {
            predicates.add(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("data_coleta"), tagsDayFilter.getDataInicial()));
        }
        if(tagsDayFilter.getDataFinal() != null) {
            predicates.add(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("data_coleta"), tagsDayFilter.getDataFinal()));
        }

        return predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]);
    }



}
```

e na URL faço: `localhost:8080/tagsday/search?ids=1,2&dataInicial=2018-09-27&dataFinal=2018-09-28`

Comment: Qual o erro? Coloca na descrição da pergunta.

Comment: Não gera nenhum erro, apenas não retorna nada. A query foi gerada dessa forma: select tagsday0_.id as id1_2_, tagsday0_.data_coleta as data_col2_2_, tagsday0_.tags_id as tags_id4_2_, tagsday0_.valor as valor3_2_ from tags_day tagsday0_ where tagsday0_.id=1 and tagsday0_.id=2 and tagsday0_.data_coleta>=? and tagsday0_.data_coleta<=?

Comment: Já tentou usar `@Query`, montando uma consulta personalizada? Algo como `@Query("SELECT t FROM TagsDay t WHERE t.id IN (?1) AND (t.data BETWEEN ?2 AND ?3)")`, em que 1 é a lista, 2 seria a data inicial e 3 a data final. Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422953/spring-data-jpa-query-arraylist-as-param)

Comment: Bom dia, então, eu gostaria de manter dessa forma pois preciso entender como funciona, via SQL normal seria bem fácil. Uma coisa que percebi é que se ao invés da consulta gerar um AND, a mesma fosse por OR funcionaria. É possível fazer essa mudança?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Para passar vários ids

Simplesmente acrescente ao query param aquele atributo várias vezes !

```
// Exemplo passando um queryParam com vários ids
localhost:8080/tagsday/search?ids=1&ids=2&dataInicial=2018-09-27&dataFinal=2018-09-28
```

Perceba que aparece "?ids=1&ids=2" essa repetição é entendida como um array(ou Lista) pelo método !

## Sobre a duvida de acrescentar OR a chamada do Criteria

Há uma forma de fazer um OR sim !!

Aqui eu criei um método para retornar os predicados em forma de OR :

```
protected Predicate[] orPredicates(CriteriaBuilder builder, List<Predicate> predicates) {
    List<Predicate> returnPredicate = new ArrayList<>();

    if(predicates.size() > 0) {
        Predicate orPredicate = builder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        returnPredicate.add(orPredicate);
    }

    return returnPredicate.toArray(new Predicate[returnPredicate.size()]);  
}
```

e uso da seguinte forma, ao invés de retornar:

```
return predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]);
```

eu retorno o método:

```
return orPredicates(builder, predicates);
```

.

### Mas, e se precisar ter alguns predicados com AND e outros com o OR ?

Você deve ter percebido que a solução anterior fará com que TODOS os predicates fiquem com OR !! 
Por causa disso, quando eu quero incluir uma parte da querie com OR e outra com AND eu faço uma "List de Predicate local" e adiciono o retorno do método de OR no predicates mandatório da seguinte forma :

```
...
// Predicados locais que devem ser do tipo OR
List<Predicate> predicatesLocal = new ArrayList<>();

if(tagsDayFilter.getDataInicial() != null) {
    predicatesLocal.add(
        builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("data_coleta"), tagsDayFilter.getDataInicial())
    );
}

if(tagsDayFilter.getDataFinal() != null) {
    predicatesLocal.add(
        builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("data_coleta"), tagsDayFilter.getDataFinal())
    );
}       

Predicate pred = builder.or( orPredicates(builder, predicatesLocal) );
predicates.add(pred);
...
```

No final ele montá o predicado como deve ser montado !

Código final do método de restrições:

```
private Predicate[] criarRestricoes(List<Long> ids, TagsDayFilter tagsDayFilter, 
                                    CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<TagsDay> root) {
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();     

    if(ids.size() > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
            //adiciona vários ids para consulta 
            predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("id"), ids.get(i)));  
        }
    }

    // ----------------- PREDICADOS COM OR -----------------        
    // Predicados locais que devem ser do tipo OR
    List<Predicate> predicatesLocal = new ArrayList<>();

    if(tagsDayFilter.getDataInicial() != null) {
        predicatesLocal.add(
            builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("data_coleta"), tagsDayFilter.getDataInicial())
        );
    }

    if(tagsDayFilter.getDataFinal() != null) {
        predicatesLocal.add(
            builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("data_coleta"), tagsDayFilter.getDataFinal())
        );
    }       

    Predicate pred = builder.or( orPredicates(builder, predicatesLocal) );
    predicates.add(pred);
    // -----------------------------------------------------

    return predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]);
}
```

Esse método irá retornar um SQL parecido com :

```
SELECT TAG.id, TAG.data_coleta, TAG.tags_id, TAG.valor
  FROM tags_day TAG
 WHERE TAG.id = 1
   AND TAG.id = 2
   AND (TAG.data_coleta >= ? OR TAG.data_coleta <= ?)
```